Safe declarative programming in Clojure?
I thought I had a smart idea. I want to make call-back functions for database calls. Usually, you would make something like:
(defn on-doc-insert [ts doc] ; the call-back
  (do-something-with-doc doc))

(db/on-insert :coll on-doc-insert) ; defining the call-back for collection :coll

Now my smart idea was to declare the call-back with meta info:
(defn ^{:on-insert :coll} on-doc-insert [ts doc]
  (do-something-with-doc doc))

Then there's no need to manually define it with a procedural function call. The program looks for all tagged functions on start-up and stores them.
The problem is that there's no easy way of checking namespaces. All tagged functions are collected, regardless of where they were defined, which of course raises some security concerns.
Is there a smarter way of doing this? I like declarative programming so it would be nice if there is.

Not sure but maybe ns-publics can come to your rescue (check this doc).
So we create a function to filter tagged functions from our namespace of interest:
(defn filter-interesting-functions [ns-symbol tag]
  (->> (ns-publics ns-symbol)
       vals
       (filter #(= (tag (meta %)) (:tag (meta %))))
       (map var-get)))

(defn register-our-handler [namespaces tag]
  (doseq [ns namespaces
          handler (filter-interesting-functions ns tag)]
    (db/on-insert (:on-insert (meta handler)) handler)))

On app start up, you can initialize the handler(s) as:
(register-our-handlers '[myproject.ns1 myproject.ns2] :on-insert)

That might handle your approach.
Another "dirty" way that might work is creating an atom map of namespaces and public functions and there tags on start up. Then do a look-up of the tag in the map and execute the function of interest using ns-resolve

Yes, I was hoping not having to add explicitly the allowed namespaces.

I myself would definitely go the most explicit and simplest route with calling db/on-insert manually. I don't think that tying a particular callback to a particular collection is a thing that makes perceived declarativeness worth pursuing.
As an alternative, whatever gathers the callback vars based on the metadata can simply check vars that are in some set of allowed namespaces.
As kind of a middle ground, you can build a registry of vars in each namespace and call a single function to process all the function in the registry at once.
